# Select year and quarters between two date columns in multiple rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two tables

Table QuarterIssue

| id | Acq_Date | Dis_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-08-07 | 2016-12-31 |
| 2 | 2018-01-05 | 2022-12-31 |
| 3 | 2019-06-21 | 2022-12-31 |

Table QuarterYear

| Year | Quarter |
| --- | --- |
| 2014 | 1 |
| 2014 | 2 |
| 2014 | 3 |
| 2014 | 4 |
| 2015 | 1 |
| 2015 | 2 |
| 2015 | 3 |
| 2015 | 4 |
| 2016 | 1 |

The QuarterYear table is a master table which has all the years and quarters.

I have a custom requirement to write a query to get the quarters between two dates from these following two tables. I have to select all the years and quarters between Acq_Date and Dis_Date for all "ids" in the QuarterIssue table. Basically my result has to be,

| YEAR | Quarter |
| --- | --- |
| 2015 | 3 |
| 2015 | 4 |
| 2016 | 1 |
| 2016 | 2 |
| 2016 | 3 |
| 2016 | 4 |
| 2018 | 1 |
| 2018 | 2 |
| 2018 | 3 |
| 2018 | 4 |
| 2019 | 1 |
| 2019 | 2 |
| 2019 | 3 |
| 2019 | 4 |
| 2020 | 1 |
| 2020 | 2 |
| 2020 | 3 |
| 2020 | 4 |
| 2021 | 1 |
| 2021 | 2 |
| 2021 | 3 |
| 2021 | 4 |
| 2022 | 1 |
| 2022 | 2 |
| 2022 | 3 |
| 2022 | 4 |

This is what I have so far,

```
SELECT [YEAR], [Quarter], ([YEAR] + CAST([Quarter] AS DECIMAL)/10) A FROM QuarterYear QY 
WHERE ([YEAR] + CAST([Quarter] AS DECIMAL)/10) 
between 
(SELECT top 1 YEAR(Acq_Date) + CAST(DATEPART(qq, Acq_Date) AS DECIMAL)/10 as ACQ FROM 
QuarterIssue) 
and 
(SELECT top 1 YEAR(Dis_Date) + CAST(DATEPART(qq, Dis_Date) AS DECIMAL)/10 as DIS FROM 
QuarterIssue)
```

As you can see right now I'm able to get the desired result of one of the "id" at a time. Is there any way we can use join or subquery to return the results I'm expecting?

Comment: Not every one defines a quarter the same way. Therefore, the `QuarterYear` table really also ought to have an additional `DateTime` column to identify the first day of each quarter.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes I understand. My actual application data has all the information. I just made this up for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it without the `DISTINCT`, if you're into that kind of thing (`DISTINCT` is often a very inefficient way - by means of a distinct sort - to hide the fact that a join returned too many rows because multiple rows matched).

Basically, we just convert each quarter from your master table into a start and end date, and then check for rows in the issue table that overlap (and [I describe the overlap pattern here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5854/using-tsql-to-find-events-that-overlap-or-dont-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)).

```
;WITH QuarterRange AS
(
  SELECT Year, Quarter, 
    RangeStart = DATEADD(MONTH, 3*(Quarter-1), 
                 DATEFROMPARTS(Year, 1, 1))
  FROM dbo.QuarterYear
)
SELECT Year, Quarter 
FROM QuarterRange AS qr
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.QuarterIssue AS qi
    WHERE qi.Dis_Date >= qr.RangeStart
      AND qi.Acq_Date <  DATEADD(MONTH, 3, qr.RangeStart)
)
ORDER BY Year, Quarter;
```

- [Working db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/m4Il6Upy?hide=4)